# What is the msvc compatible version of format specifier %qi?

Tags: visual-c++, c99

Im porting some gcc code, ran into an error "Expression: (Incorrect format specifier), 0". I checked whats being passed to sprintf (defined by me) and its %qi. From what I saw in google, its some sort of c99 thing. What would be(if any) the msvc comaptible version?

The specifier is utilized as follows:

```
(void)snprintf(val, 64, "%"PRIi64, node_data->intval);
```

and defined: (in inttypes.h that came with the project)

```
#define __PRI_64_LENGTH_MODIFIER__ "q"
#define PRIi64        __PRI_64_LENGTH_MODIFIER__ "i"
```

the node_data->intval appears to be uint64_t

Comment: You can look here for apropriate in your case specifier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx

Comment: If you provide more information about what you use in sprintf with %qi it would be more informative for the answerers.

Comment: I've yet to find it, i suspect its in a macro somewhere

Comment: Think I found it, give me a minute to figure out how it goes together

Comment: I think I found the equivalent too - %I64i

Comment: you can see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx that "I64" with "d, i, o, x, or X" stands for __int64 type. For unsigned __int64 they adviced using "I64" with "o, u, x, or X"

Answer (score 0):

`PRIi64` (and its equivalent `PRId64`) are cross-platform C99 format specifiers used for 64-byte integers.

MSVC doesn't support C99, but it has its own format specifier for that purpose - `"%I64d"` (or `"%I64i"` if you prefer `i` over `d`).

A sidenote on the header files sources you posted: that seems to be GCC's `inttypes.h`, a C99-standard file. Here's how it defines `PRIi64`:

In GCC, the `%q` (extension) format prefix means "quad". It's used for the `quad_t` GCC type, which is defined as `typedef long long int quad_t;` (unsigned version: `typedef unsigned long long int u_quad_t;`). It can be used with the standard number formats: `"%qd %qi %qo %qu %qx %qX %qn"`.

If you want to reduce changes to the code itself, you can just modify the `#define` in the header you're using and replace GCC's `%q` format prefix with MSVC's `%I64` format prefix:

```
#define __PRI_64_LENGTH_MODIFIER__ "I64"
```